# Compose Dialog closing on keyboard appearance when LazyColumn is in background

Tags: android, keyboard, dialog, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have a layout where each item in a `LazyColumn` can display an item-specific dialog. The `Dialogs` showed and worked fine except for some of the larger ones where whenever I would try to edit text in one of the dialog's `TextFields` it would trigger the dialog to disappear.

I tried a lot of different approaches and the weirdest thing was that **the dialog works fine** and allows me do edit the textfields **if I only scroll the `LazyColumn`** by even 1 item before attempting to show the dialog.

It has proven hard to reproduce the issue in a simple setting as changing even basic elements of my code makes the bug disappear but I finally managed. The appearance of the bug seems to depend on the `LazyColumn` being `Scrollable` and on the KeyBoard to be of type text. Next a somewhat long code sample and a GIF showing the issue:

```
@Composable
fun JointCourseTemplate(courseTemplateDto: CourseTemplateDto) {
    LazyColumn(
        //state= LazyListState()
    ){
        for(i in 0..4){
            item { TestPart(i = i) }
            for (j in 0..8){
                item { TestItem(i = j) }
            }
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun TestPart(i:Int) {
    var showDialog by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Row(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        Text("part"+i)
        Button(onClick = { showDialog=true }) {
            Text("show dialog")
        }
    }
    
    PartDialog(showDialog = showDialog, hideDialog = {showDialog=false}) 
}

@Composable
fun TestItem(i:Int) {
    Row(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        Text("item"+i)
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text("show dialog")
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun PartDialog(showDialog:Boolean, hideDialog: () -> Unit) {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    if (showDialog) {
        Dialog(properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnClickOutside = false,
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
        ),
            onDismissRequest = { hideDialog() }) {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    //.wrapContentHeight()
                    //.fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
                    .width(400.dp)
                    .height(600.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
            ) {
                Column {
                    Text(text = "Some Dialog")
                    OutlinedTextField(value = text, onValueChange = {text=it}, label = { Text(text = "TroubleMaker")})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If that's a bug, it should be reported. Your fix is far from perfect, `LazyColumn` should not work correctly with it

Comment: @Philip Dukhov I'm on it. The thing is my code is quite long so i will have to workon it a bit. however I do not understand why LazyColumn should not work If I give it an instance of LazyListState, this is after all an argument that it accepts

Comment: You gonna create a new list state on each recomposition. Check out [this](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/5b1ed0cd925dc3a88a7392cbd4b2d1a1) example, and try to scroll the list - scroll position is gonna be reset on each recomposition.

Comment: @Philip Dukhov You are correct, It didnt affect me as my lazyColumn was only composed once but I have extracted and persisted my liststate with remember so it solves the issue in a more general setting. let me know if its documented enough for you to reproduce. Unless you see any mistake from my side I will report this later on

Comment: With this solution it's not gonna save scroll position after device rotation, and if you made it `rememberSaveable` you'll end up duplicating `rememberLazyListState`, which is the default value and should be used at the end. Checking out on your code

Comment: in fact I just realized that in the test code I provided not even my solution is working. not sure what changed. It only affects the second visible TestPart item before you scroll as seen in the gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to the fact that you open the dialog from a lazy cell, which is located at the bottom of the screen. Therefore, when the keyboard appears, this cell becomes invisible and is removed from the view tree. I would say this is intended behavior.

I would suggest that you move the dialog from `LazyColumn`. Perhaps you need information about a particular item to be displayed inside the dialog, you can store the selected item instead of a boolean value:

```kotlin
val (selectedDialogItem, setSelectedItem) = remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
LazyColumn {
    items(4) { i ->
        Row(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            Text("part"+i)
            Button(onClick = {
                setSelectedItem(i)
            }) {
                Text("show dialog")
            }
        }
    }
}
if (selectedDialogItem != null) {
    Dialog(
        // ...
    )
}
```

p.s. I'm not using delegation here to allow `selectedDialogItem` smart cast inside `if` block

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced this is a bug that needs fixing by google however the simple solution is to add the state argument to the LazyColumn as shown.

```
val listState by remember{mutableStateOf(LazyListState())}
LazyColumn(state = listState  ){...}
```

I realize this is quite a niche bug but maybe it helps someone else save time

**EDIT**

This was clearly wrong and dindt always work. not sure why it worked the first time around